# Select all rows with maximum value of a temporary table

Tags: mysql, max, temporary

I'd like to select all the rows from a temporary table that have a value equal to the maximum value.

### TEMPORARY TABLE test

```
id | value
1  | 7
2  | 6
3  | 7
```

### Expected result:

```
id | value
1  | 7
3  | 7
```

I've already tried several things but all attempts (except creating another temporary table with the same content) failed so far because of "You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query." (Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html).
Is there a possibility to do this in a more "elegant" way than copying the table and its contents?

What I've tested so far:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM test table1 LEFT JOIN test table2 ON table1.value < table2.value     
WHERE table2.value IS NULL;
SELECT * FROM test WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM test);
```

And this is my current solution:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test2 (...);
INSERT INTO test2 SELECT * FROM test;
SELECT * FROM test WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM test2);
```

Comment: Can you list some of the things you've tried?

Comment: SELECT * FROM test WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM test);

Comment: You should add that to the question... also, you said several attempts, so it would be useful to see the variations that you tried.

Comment: Ok, I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using variables. The following will scan the test table only once (not-tested):

```
SELECT   test.*, 
         @curMax := IF(@curMax = -1, value, @curMax)
FROM     test,
         (SELECT @curMax := -1) r
HAVING   @curMax = value OR @curMax = -1
ORDER BY value DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks :) This works and I'd like to use it if there's a way to not display both columns "test.value" and "@curMax := IF(@curMax = -1, value, @curMax)". Is it possible to change the statement that the maximum value will be displayed only once?

Comment: Oh, yes you should be able to wrap the entire thing with "SELECT value FROM ( ... ) d;" ... You should be able to select the visible columns in this outer query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id,value From SomeTable
inner Join (Select Max(SomeValue) as MaximumValue From SomeTable) maximums
  On SomeTable.Value = maximums.MaximumValue
```

Should do the job

Comment: This results in two errors: The first one is "Every derived table must have it's own alias" and after fixing this one "Can't reopen table SomeTable"

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT MAX(value) INTO @max
FROM test;

SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE value = @max;
```